# T-SQL help - can someone think of a set-based operation to replace our current row-basead operation in sql instead?

Tags: sql, database, string, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

I have a question in one of the process, currently it's written in row-based operation, and it takes an hour to populate around 50,000 records but will take over 5 days for 3million records.  I have been trying to think of a different approach which involve only set-based tsql and not use row-by-row/cursor, it is the cursor that makes the process super slow, but can't think of any other ways.  Can someone help?  Here's what I am trying to accomplish, basically I have a table of email addresses which gets updated everyday, and I need to parse out each part and add them to a separate email part table.

The email address table is in this format:
[image]

Note that the domain or mailbox can be empty values, but not both.  And all email addresses are unique in the table.

Specs:

(1) The full domain is split by “.” into parts. Each part is added to the Parts table. The right-most part is assigned a “level” value of 0. The left-most part, which is the part immediately after the @ sign, is given an “is_leaf_domain” value of 1. Otherwise, parts are numbered starting at zero on the right-most part, and increasing to the left.

(2) The mailbox is added to the Parts table as-is, with “is_address” value of 1 and a “level” value of the number of parts in the domain, plus one.

(3) Each address will have a "is.address"  and "is_leaf_domain" part, even if they are empty value.

Based on  specs abive, the above email address would get parsed out and inserted into the parts table in this manner in the parts table:

[image]

I can only think of a row-by-row operation to accomplish this.  I Look at each email address in the email table one row at a time, starting by looking at the right most character of the fulldomain string, moving to the left one character at a time until I hit a ".", and insert that part into the parts table with level 0, then keep doing the same thing and adding one to the level everytime a new part is inserted, when I hit the left most (the beginning) of the string and I can't go further left anymore, that part will have "is_leaf_domain" = 1, with the appropriate label and level_con and parent_con being inserted.  After that is done the final step would be to just add the whole mailbox to the parts table, with level being the previous level + 1 , "is.address" = 1, and the fulldomain from email table being the parent_con.

Populating Parent_con/level_con values are pretty much self-explanatory by looking at the parts table below.

For empty fulldomain, I just inserted a blank value into the parts table with "is_leaf_domain" = 1 with empty level_con and empty parent_con.

For empty mailbox, I just inserted a blank value into the parts table with "is_address" = 1 and empty level_con (all mailbox/is_address = 1  has empty value as level_con), and the full_domain from email table as parent_con.

With this approach, I am looking at one record/email at a time, parse out the string by moving from right to left and insert each part into the parts table, then move on to the next record.. and it's taking forever for email table containing millions of rows, as some email address can have over 10 levels or so...

Is there a easier way to do this without using row-by-row operation but using a set-based approach?

I thought about creating a temp table that maybe calculate the position of each "." using charindex() and using substring() to get the parts out based on the differnet position I recorded in the temp table, but I really have no idea how to start, especially there are many email addresses that have over 10 parts to up to 30 parts...

Does anyone have any idea how to approach this in a set-based approach? My row-based approach works but takes a long time for over million records, if someone can think of another approach I would be greatly appreciated, and if you can write out the whole code for me in t-sql in sql server 2008 or even create a stored procedure for me that I can just run, I would be forever in your debt :)

Or if someone can tell me there is no way to do this except doing it row-by-row, I would be greatly appreciated too as I will stop thinking about it :)

thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: Is there a maximum number of Parts in the Fulldomain?

Comment: no, there is no max, I have seen fulldomain with over 50 parts, almost all of them are data error with that many parts, but we don't catch it.  we will just insert those 50 parts to the parts table

Comment: How do you use these parsing results? Can they be generated lazily (only when needed)?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming I'm following you...

You actually have 3 distinct sets in your parts table.  Is_address records, is_leaf_domain records, and then the exploded email domain records.

The first two are pretty easy to handle and I've done so below.  Note - there's some repeated crap that I would handle with additional columns on your source table or by creating a temp table with the break ups.  For example, I would break RightOfThe@ to a column and the same for LeftOfThe@.  As it is I have the same substring/charindex stuff repeated multiple times.

You should be able to take SQL below and run it in your own environment (probably have to make the TempTbl schema or drop the schema specification):

```
IF  EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.objects WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[TempTbl].[Addr]') AND type in (N'U'))
DROP TABLE TempTbl.Addr
GO   


CREATE TABLE TempTbl.Addr (
  AddressID INT,
  Clean_Address varchar(100),
  Mailbox varchar(100),
  Fulldomain varchar(100)
  )

GO

INSERT INTO TempTbl.Addr VALUES (1,'john.scott@gmail.com','john.scott','gmail.com');
INSERT INTO TempTbl.Addr VALUES (2,'joseph@ny.email.gs.com','joseph','ny.email.gs.com');
INSERT INTO TempTbl.Addr VALUES (3,'@cornell.edu','','cornell.edu');
INSERT INTO TempTbl.Addr VALUES (4,'lenny@','Lenny','');

GO

select
    AddressID,
    LevelCol = LEN(Clean_address) - LEN(REPLACE(Clean_Address,'.','')) + 1,
    Label = SUBSTRING(Clean_address,0,COALESCE(CHARINDEX('@',clean_address),0)),
    Level_Con = '',
    Parent_Con = SUBSTRING(Clean_address,COALESCE(CHARINDEX('@',clean_address) + 1,0),999),
    is_address = 1,
    is_leaf_domain = 0
FROM TempTbl.Addr
UNION
select
    AddressID,
    LevelCol = LEN(SUBSTRING(Clean_address,COALESCE(CHARINDEX('@',clean_address),0),999)) - LEN(REPLACE(SUBSTRING(Clean_address,COALESCE(CHARINDEX('@',clean_address),0),999),'.','')),
    Label = SUBSTRING(
                SUBSTRING(Clean_address,COALESCE(CHARINDEX('@',clean_address) + 1,0),999),
                0,
                CHARINDEX('.',SUBSTRING(Clean_address,COALESCE(CHARINDEX('@',clean_address) + 1,0),999))),
    Level_Con = SUBSTRING(Clean_address,COALESCE(CHARINDEX('@',clean_address) + 1,0),999),
    Parent_Con = SUBSTRING(
                SUBSTRING(Clean_address,COALESCE(CHARINDEX('@',clean_address) + 1,0),999),
                CHARINDEX('.',SUBSTRING(Clean_address,COALESCE(CHARINDEX('@',clean_address) + 1,0),999))
                ,999),

    is_address = 0,
    is_leaf_domain = 1
FROM TempTbl.Addr
ORDER BY AddressID, LevelCol DESC
```

Let me know if this helps.  This was what I could get today for sure.  I'll think on the exploding set, or maybe somebody gets to it before me.

---

I'm pretty close to the last piece but I've gotta run and I won't be able to get back to this for at least a couple days. See where this gets you.  I'm using recursion to explode it out for each piece between a dot.

```
SELECT
  AddressID,
  LevelCol = 0,
  Clean_Address,
  RightOfAt = SUBSTRING(Clean_address,COALESCE(CHARINDEX('@',clean_address) + 1,0),999),
  Mailbox,
  Fulldomain   INTO #T
  from TempTbl.Addr
  WHERE SUBSTRING(Clean_address,COALESCE(CHARINDEX('@',clean_address) + 1,0),999) > '';


WITH T as (
SELECT 
    AddressID,
    LevelCol,
    0 AS r,
    CurrentLocation = 0, 
    RightOfAt,
    CHARINDEX('.',REVERSE(RightOfAt)) AS DotIndex FROM #T
UNION ALL
SELECT 
    AddressID,
    LevelCol = LevelCol + 1,
    DotIndex + 1 AS r,
    CurrentLocation = DotIndex,
    RightOfAt,  
    DotIndex = 
    CHARINDEX('.',REVERSE(RightOfAt),DotIndex + 1)
    FROM T
    WHERE DotIndex > 0 --Reach Zero in recursion when there are no more located
)

SELECT 
AddressID,
LevelCol,
--CurrentLocation,
--DotIndex,
Label = 
    CASE 
        WHEN DotIndex > 0 THEN REVERSE(SUBSTRING(REVERSE(RightOfAt),CurrentLocation, DotIndex))
        ELSE REVERSE(SUBSTRING(REVERSE(RightOfAt),CurrentLocation + 1, 9999))
    END,
Parent_Con = RightOfAt,
REVERSE(RightOfAt),
is_address = 0,
is_leaf_domain = 0
FROM T
WHERE DotIndex <> 0
ORDER BY AddressID, LevelCol DESC

DROP TABLE #T;
```

Comment: This definitely helps for highest 2 most levels, the is_address = 1 and is_leaf_domain = 1 level!!  As for the other levels underneath them, is there a way to do it with set-based??? some  addresses contains over 30 levels :(     thanks so much :)  if it's possible, I would very much appreciate it!!

Comment: I've updated my answer to reflect #3 as close as I could get it today.   Will be awhile before I can poke it again, I won't be in front of a computer with SQL, but I think you're just down to the Label column getting parsed correctly.

Comment: cool thanks for the thelp :)  I will await your final code :)

Answer (score 1):

This was an awesome challenge... Not sure I'll have the best/fastest performing answer, but here it is none-the-less.

I have included a 22-part domain, and it appears to be working just fine.

Hope you find it useful.

Once you have done this, I would set some sort of bit flag on your source to indicate it's complete, so you don't have to repeatedly re-parse millions of rows of data.  Then re-set that flag on updated address' and of course new inserts.

UPDATE: edited to not split mailbox per example data.

```
DECLARE @Emails TABLE (AddressID INT, Clean_Address NVARCHAR(MAX), Mailbox NVARCHAR(MAX), FullDomain NVARCHAR(MAX))
DECLARE @Parts TABLE (AddressID INT, [Level] INT, Label NVARCHAR(MAX), Level_Con NVARCHAR(MAX), Parent_Con NVARCHAR(MAX), is_address BIT, is_leaf_domain BIT)

INSERT INTO @Emails
   VALUES (1, 'john.scott@gmail.com', 'john.scott', 'gmail.com'),
          (2, 'joseph@ny.email.gs.com', 'joseph', 'ny.email.gs.com'),
          (3, '@cornell.edu', '', 'cornell.edu'),
          (4, 'lenny@', 'Lenny', ''),
          (5, 'johnny@ny.really.long.domain.email.thats.impossible.to.remember.com', 'johnny', 'ny.really.long.domain.email.thats.impossible.to.remember.com'),
          (6, 'johnny@ny.really.long.domain.email.thats.impossible.to.remember.and.everyone.hates.to.type.out.because.their.fingers.cramp.and.such.com', 'johnny', 'ny.really.long.domain.email.thats.impossible.to.remember.and.everyone.hates.to.type.out.because.their.fingers.cramp.and.such.com')

;WITH SplitData (AddressID, String, RowID, levelCount, lrSource, oValue) AS (
    SELECT DISTINCT AddressID, 
           Mailbox AS String,
           ROW_NUMBER() over(order by (select null)) as ROWID,
           SUM(1) over(PARTITION by addressid)-1 as levelCount,
           1 AS lrSource,
           Mailbox
    FROM @Emails

    UNION ALL

    SELECT DISTINCT A.AddressID,  
           Split.a.value('.', 'NVARCHAR(max)') AS String,
           ROW_NUMBER() over(order by (select null)) as ROWID,
           SUM(1) over(PARTITION by addressid)-1 as levelCount,
           2 AS lrSource,
           FullDomain
    FROM  (SELECT AddressID, FullDomain,
                  CAST ('<M>' + REPLACE(CAST(FullDomain AS VARCHAR(MAX)), '.', '</M><M>') + '</M>' AS XML) AS String  
           FROM @Emails) AS A 
    CROSS APPLY String.nodes ('/M') AS Split(a)
),
OrderedSplitData AS (
    SELECT AddressID, String, lrSource, oValue, levelCount,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY ADDRESSID ORDER BY lrSource DESC, ROWID DESC)-1 AS [LevelID],
           SUM(1) over(PARTITION by addressid)-1 as maxCount
    FROM SplitData
),
OrderedSplitDataRecursion AS (
    select AddressID, String, lrSource, oValue, right(oValue,LEN(ovalue)-len(string)-case when len(string)=0 then 0 else 1 end) as [nValue], levelCount, LevelID, maxCount
    from OrderedSplitData
    where lrSource=2
    and LevelID=levelCount
    union all
    select OSDR.AddressID, OSD.String, OSDR.lrSource, nValue, right(nValue,LEN(nvalue)-len(OSD.String)-case when OSDR.LevelID-1=0 then 0 else 1 end), OSDR.levelCount, OSDR.LevelID-1, OSDR.maxCount
    from OrderedSplitDataRecursion OSDR
    join OrderedSplitData OSD ON OSDR.LevelID-1=OSD.LevelID and OSD.lrSource=2 AND OSDR.AddressID=OSD.AddressID
    where OSDR.lrSource=2
    and OSDR.LevelID-1<OSDR.levelCount
    and OSDR.LevelID-1>=0
)

--select * from SplitData
--select * from OrderedSplitData
--select * from OrderedSplitDataRecursion

insert into @Parts
-- record for address
select OSD.AddressID, 
       OSD.LevelID, 
       E.Mailbox as label, 
       '' AS level_con, 
       E.FullDomain as parent_con, 
       1 as is_address, 0 as is_leaf_domain
from OrderedSplitData OSD
JOIN @Emails E ON OSD.AddressID = E.AddressID
where lrSource=1
and LevelID=maxCount
-- all other levels
union
select OSD.AddressID, 
       OSD.LevelID, 
       OSD.String as label, 
       oValue as level_con, 
       nValue as parent_con, 
       0 as is_address, 
       case when LevelID=levelCount then 1 else 0 end as is_leaf_domain
from OrderedSplitDataRecursion OSD
where OSD.lrSource=2
ORDER BY OSD.AddressID, OSD.LevelID DESC

select *
from @Parts
```

Comment: John scott  should be level 2 ::( it was a typo.  yea I only process the new emails everyday. not the ones that' already aprocessed :) thanks!

Comment: how did you get john to be level 3? I look thru the code can't find it to change that part back :P

Comment: oo I fixed it to match what I needed. you are good!! this code is great :)

Comment: Glad you got it sorted out!  Removing the splitting of the mailbox will make this faster!

Comment: I have updated my answer so the mailbox is not split.

Comment: hehe thanks. that is what i did too finally :) thanks for all your help! i realy apprecaite it!